# Is WAV needed for html5 audio fully cross-browser?

Tags: audio, wav, mp4, ogg, webm

An audio for the web which is fully cross-browser needs some different formats to work on all browsers. Commonly I see that people use `mp4` and `ogg`. But I want to be completely sure. Therefore I added `webm` and `wav`. Is this completely needed? Especially wav files as they are so heavy. This question should be thought thinking about performance for a responsive site.

This is my html example:

```
<audio controls="controls" data-music="1">
    <source src="http://example.webm" type="audio/webm" />
    <source src="http://example.mp4" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://example.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://example.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

Will this all be downloaded and affect the global performance?

Additionally, does the order matter of the type of formats?

Comment: webm and mp4 are typically *video* files. What are you doing to encode your audio in those container formats?

Comment: @Quentin encode your audio? I just add these formats on the htaccess if thats what you mean. Ok, its typically for video but is it wrong to use them for audio? Are they necessary? If the answer is not a NO or YES, then... is it better for cross-browser? And finally, what about WAV?

Comment: how about mp3? -WAV is not always supported (if you add WAV, I would also expect that you added AIFF, which is the WAV equivalent on Mac). mp3 is probably the most used, but I would also recommend ogg. Remember there's also MID files (MIDI), which is also widely used. Sadly, .MOD is almost never recognized.

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero — You have to put the sound in a file somehow, otherwise you have nothing to send to the browser when they ask for the URL. How are you making your audio mp4 file? or your audio webm file?

Comment: @Quentin I'm using http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ to create each format. This programs works very well.